# Eclipse BIRT data set from BlueAnt shows keys only

Tags: eclipse, dataset, birt

I have got the following problem when I try to add a data set from BlueAnt to my BIRT-Report in eclipse:
The *preview result function* shows the following data only:

```
Offer_No         Status               Sum
quotenumber 171  quoteState.text 171  171.0
quotenumber 172  quoteState.text 172  172.0
quotenumber 173  quoteState.text 173  173.0
quotenumber 174  quoteState.text 174  174.0
quotenumber 175  quoteState.text 175  175.0
```

That's all, no more records.
These entries seem like references with subdata?

I expected something like:

```
Offer_No         Status               Sum
171              'sent to customer'   2400
```

To add BlueAnt as a Data Source I had to download a report.xml (92KB) and a report_messages.xgz (3.6MB) file from the project management tool and copy it to eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar issue.
My MacBook Pro with OS X 10.10.3 is *en_US*, but the downloaded files are localized in German (*de_DE*) and English (*en*)

The problem is that the English localization is just set to *en*.
A search and replace in `report_messages.xgz` from *de_DE* to *en_US* solved the problem after an Eclipse restart, since I needed the German names. If you want the English localization, replace *en* with *en_US*